# NSFileProtectionNone is missing in Apple Account

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, provisioning-profile, data-protection

There are [four types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfileprotectiontype?language=objc) of file protection mode by Apple. i.e.

[image]

But in my apple account data protection section I see `NSFileProtectionNone` is missing. Below is the snapshot of my account bundle config,

[image]

How can I disable protection for all kind of data in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this reference (https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/how-to-use-ios-data-protection/)

> The place to navigate to on the website is: Identifiers > App IDs > (the app ID) > Edit > Data Protection > Sharing and Permissions. This can be set to one of the three protection levels (but not NSFileProtectionNone).
>
> NSFileProtectionNone - You can’t make this the default because there is no option for this in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section of the Apple developer website. You wouldn’t want that anyway.